# AVPlayer fails to load files during unit tests on CI servers

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, avplayer

I have some unit tests which cause `AVPlayer` to load a local file. The file is a tiny (~2KB) `m4a` audio file in the test bundle. The tests all work locally for me.

When setting up my project on Travis, I noticed the tests that cause `AVPlayer` to load a file failed. I tried several other CI services and had the same problem. I increased the test timeout but no luck. All other tests pass.

I load files something like the following (simplified):

```
let path = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).path(forResource: "Pop", ofType: "m4a")!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: url)

self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url))
```

My code observes `AVPlayer.currentItem.status`. When running on CI, the observer fires with status `.failed`. The `player.error` is `nil`, and the `player.currentItem.error` is:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f86e1cd8070 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-101 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-101), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Interestingly, in another test where I deliberately try to load a corrupted file (to assert it can't be played and that my code returns relevant errors), I get the following error which is expected and suggests there’s no problem reading from the filesystem:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11829 "Cannot Open" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f86e1cd7ba0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12848 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This media may be damaged., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Open}
```

**Update**

I’ve seen that testing locally I occasionally (maybe once in a day’s work) get a similar failure. It seems to be when I've opened Xcode and the project fresh, and works thereafter. Maybe something in `AVFoundation` is taking a while to initialise? I'd love to be able to mock `AVPlayer`, perhaps I’ll get around to adding a protocol for that and `AVPlayerItem`...

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried sshing to your own machine and running the test?

Comment: Yes, all tests pass.

Comment: One of the errors corresponds to `AVErrorFileFailedToParse`. Could the files be corrupt? Or unreadable due to permissions? Or missing? Spotlight used to cause occasional problems by opening files (exclusively?) at unexpected times.

Comment: Aha, permissions sounds like a good bet. Yes the second error is from a deliberately corrupt file to test my error handling, but as stated that error is expected and handled (https://github.com/lstn-ltd/lstn-sdk-ios/blob/master/Example/Tests/Audio/DefaultAudioEngineSpec.swift#L66).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue and the same error.
I initially tried with no luck, both with video and audio files.
Then, I have solved the issue creating a video with no audio. 
I suspect the issue is caused by Travis-CI's vm not having a sound card and causing the OS to miss something to be able to reproduce the file.

Although, I am not 100% sure if it's the lack of audio or the way the video has been exported that fixes the issue.

[videoOnlyTest.mp4](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=97027206291331691567)

Comment: I think this is probably the underlying problem — AVPlayer does rely on having an audio interface. It's a real pain this stuff is so hard to unit test!

Comment: My final conclusion is that `AVFoundation` playback simply won't work on CI where there's (probably) no audio hardware. That's understandable in itself, but frustrating as the API isn't based on protocols and is a pain to mock in Swift. I ended up turning off audio tests with the following switch: `-skip-testing:MyTests/AudioEngineSpec`.

Comment: I had the same problem on CircleCI, using a video without audio worked like a charm.